# Изменить ширину страницы WordPress?

Tags: веб-программирование, wordpress, css

Всем привет! Проблема в следующем - не могу изменить ширину страницы. С помощью FireBug устанавливаю нужную мне ширину, выглядит прекрасно. Но я не могу найти тот файл, где это надо записать.
[Скрин моей проблемы](http://firepic.org/?v=2.2014-06-12_05k5cywrdqut.png)

FireBug указывает на **?page_id=2**, но где он храниться? Главная страница выглядит как надо, а вот созданные далее имеют одну и туже ширину. В файле style.css нет такой строки: 
width:790px;

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: в php файлах тоже такой строки нет ?

Comment: Подобный вывод означает, что css заданы прямо в теле документа. Это один из файлов шаблонов (header.php, footer.php, post.php и иже с ними), где-то в теге `<head>` должен находиться тег `<style>` с правилами (скорее всего, это header.php).

Comment: Шаблон Mantra.

Answer (score 1):

это задаётся хуком

```
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) )
    $content_width = 790;
```

Ищите такое в файле functions.php